# EF 6 Code First - Schema is not valid type not available

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I did some refactoring to a code base, and created an abstract class `SlottedHardware` that held some common properties that other classes should use.

However, I am now getting the error:
 `Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'MyProject.Models.NetworkDevice_Slots' was not loaded because the type 'MyProject.Models.Models.NetworkDevice' is not available.`

when trying to create the database by setting my DbContext ctor to `Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>());`

I have been at this for hours, and would really appreciate if someone can lend a helping hand.  Here are some of the entity classes, as well as the Fluent API mapping:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SlottedHardware : EntityBase
{
    public int MaxSlots { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Slot> Slots { get; set; }
}

public class Slot : EntityBase
{
    public string SlotIdentifier { get; set; }
    public List<Card> CompatibleCards { get; set; } = new List<Card>();
    public State State { get; set; }
    public virtual NetworkDevice NetworkDevice { get; set; }
}

public class NetworkDevice : SlottedHardware
{
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public List<UnpublishedConfig> UnpublishedConfigs { get; set; }
    public List<PublishedConfig> PublishedConfigs { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }

    /*** Constructors ***/

    public NetworkDevice()
    {
        MaxSlots = 0;
        Slots = new List<Slot>();
        UnpublishedConfigs = new List<UnpublishedConfig>();
        PublishedConfigs = new List<PublishedConfig>();
    }

    public NetworkDevice(string vendor, string model, int maxSlots) : this()
    {
        Vendor = vendor;
        Model = model;
        if(maxSlots > 0)
        {
            MaxSlots = maxSlots;
        }

    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // NetworkDevice entity
    modelBuilder.Entity<NetworkDevice>().Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("NetworkDevices");
    });
    modelBuilder.Entity<NetworkDevice>().HasKey(t => t.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<NetworkDevice>().
        HasMany(t => t.Slots).
        WithOptional(t => t.NetworkDevice);
    modelBuilder.Entity<NetworkDevice>().
        HasMany(t => t.PublishedConfigs).
        WithMany();
    modelBuilder.Entity<NetworkDevice>().
        HasMany(t => t.UnpublishedConfigs).
        WithMany();
    modelBuilder.Entity<NetworkDevice>().Property(t => t.MaxSlots).IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<NetworkDevice>().Property(t => t.Model).IsRequired();

    // Slot entity
    modelBuilder.Entity<Slot>().Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("Slots");
    });
    modelBuilder.Entity<Slot>().HasKey(t => t.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Slot>().HasOptional(t => t.NetworkDevice).WithMany(x => x.Slots);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Slot>().HasMany(t => t.CompatibleCards).WithMany(x => x.Slots);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Slot>().Property(t => t.SlotIdentifier).IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Slot>().Ignore(t => t.Card);
}
```

Comment: I think you should setting model builder like these: `modelBuilder.Entity<NetworkDevice>().HasMany(t => t.PublishedConfigs).WithMany(x => x.NetworkDevice);` & `modelBuilder.Entity<NetworkDevice>().HasMany(t => t.UnpublishedConfigs).WithMany(x => x.NetworkDevice);`. Seems that `WithMany` method for `NetworkDevice` not initialized properly on 1..n relationship.

Comment: `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` -- didn't it exist? I can create a database from this class model if I remove the references to classes not shown.